# destroy java thread

Tags: java, multithreading

help me kill java thread
So I have code:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    // process() method is time-consuming and has no while-loop in his body
    // so I want to give user to stop it
    new AnyObject().process();
  }
}).start();
```

My question is how can I kill such thread?

Comment: I am not sure if looking for a way to kill a thread is such a nice approach. What I would probably suggest is to implement `AnyObject().process()` in such a way that it is always finished.. and hence the calling thread.

Answer (score 3):

You can call Thread.stop() however you should understand what it does as its deprecated for a reason (being that it can leave your system in an inconsistent state)  If the work you are doing is self contained and well behaved, it won't be a problem.

However if it were well behaved you wouldn't need to stop it this way, thus the catch-22 with this "solution" ;)

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately the only safe way to stop a thread is to have it exit its run loop.  There are two main ways to do that, set a flag that the AnyObject.process method checks periodically or have the AnyObject.process method respond correctly to an interrupt and exit.  However to use the latter method, you will need to keep a reference to the thread around so you can issue the interrupt method on it.

You should probably keep a reference to your AnyObject as well in case you need to reference it later.

If all that fails, System.exit() will usually do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can call interrupt() on thread in order to stop it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use thread.interrupt() to stop thread!

Answer (score 0):

Your Thread will be terminated when the run() method will be terminated.

In your example, it will be when the `new AnyObject().process();` will be terminated.

So, terminate the process() method will terminate your Thread.